How do I run the same function several times using inputs with different lengths?
Suppose I have these two vectors:
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

Each of them correspond to 1 argument of a function(x, y). I want to run this function with all possible combinations between those two vectors. For example:
function("a", 1)
function("a", 2)
function("a", 3)
function("a", 4)
function("b", 1)
...
function("c", 4)

So I want to run this function 12 times, that is: length(x) * length(y). How do I accomplish this?

You can use outer() to do this.  For example,
f <- function(x, y) paste(x, y)

x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

outer(x, y, f)

If you don't want a matrix result, use c(outer(x, y, f)).  If f can't handle vector arguments, then use outer(x, y, Vectorize(f)).
